# Virtualbox inside Docker

Tags: docker, virtual-machine, containers, virtualbox

I'm trying to get VirtualBox to run inside of Docker. I'm using this: https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/jess/virtualbox/dockerfile/.

When I run the command:

```
sudo docker run -d \
    -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix \
    -e DISPLAY=unix$DISPLAY \
    --privileged \
    --name virtualbox \
    jess/virtualbox
```

It adds virtualbox inside a container. When I run `sudo docker start container_id`, it echoes back the container_id but doesn't add it to the running containers. I check with `sudo docker ps` and it is not there; however, it is there with `sudo docker ps -a`.

What am I doing wrong? I get no errors either.

EDIT: I'm running Docker in Ubuntu 15.04 (Not inside VirtualBox)

Comment: Can you add information about the host where you're running the docker daemon? e.g. are you running docker on virtualbox? I'm not sure if virtualbox can run inside virtualbox.

Comment: @Andy I'm using Ubuntu 15.04 as the host. This is not inside a virtualbox. I'll add it to the OP.

Comment: Not running demonized (-d), or getting the logs out of the stopped container would probably be helpful.

Comment: @MangledDeutz When I try to get the logs I get this `No protocol specified
Qt WARNING: VirtualBox: cannot connect to X server unix:0`. The same thing happens when I take out -d.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to let docker to connect to your local X server. There are different ways to do this. One straight way is running `xhost +local:docker` before running your container (i.e.: before `docker run`).